# Can I install Ubuntu 64 bit?

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit

I run `lscpu` and get among other information:

```
Architecture:          i686
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
```

The first line means I am running Ubuntu 32 bit.

Does the second line of the output above mean I can install **Ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso**   ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. Your CPU can run in 64-bit mode.